# Yocto u-boot Custom Commands

Tags: xilinx, yocto, u-boot, openembedded, petalinux

What is the correct way of adding custom commands to u-boot in a Yocto setup (currently using Petalinux 2016.4 by Xilinx)?

1. Should I add the relevant source files to the u-boot source through a recipe/patch, to be included in the compilation of u-boot?
2. Is there a better way to do this during development to get a faster turn around.
3. In what folder should the code be placed - under u-boot/board or added to u-boot/commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you have two options for adding the additional sourcecode to your YP build:

1. If you have only a small number of changes: Add the patches to your layer and "activate" them via `SRC_URI`.
2. If you have more changes: create a separate git branch/repo for "your" U-Boot version.

The fastest way of testing your changes may be to checkout a separate U-Boot repo somewhere and use a generated SDK. Another way may be to use the `devshell` [1]

I'm not an expert on U-Boot's source layout, but I would say it depends which type of command it is. If it's a "generic" one like `date` the `cmd/` subdirectory would be best.

If you're looking for an example on which you can base your work maybe the `timer` command in `cmd/misc.c` would be a good start.

[1] http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Devshell