# Implement custom u-boot command

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, qemu, bootloader, u-boot

I want to add custom command command to `u-boot` be it a simple hello world command.

After searching I found this link [Yocto u-boot Custom Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416296/yocto-u-boot-custom-commands) where it says to look at `timer` command in `cmd/misc.c` as starting point.

How do I bring this `timer` command to my u-boot image? 
I assume I have make changes to the makefiles but not sure which makefile I should edit.

I am using qemu to test the `u-boot` image in Ubuntu 18.04 using the following method

1. Cloned the `u-boot` source from github.
2. Installed all the build dependencies in the system.
3. Prepared u-boot config files using `make qemu_arm_config ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-`
4. Build u-boot `make all ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-`
5. Launch qemu with u-boot image `qemu-system-arm -M virt -nographic -kernel u-boot`

### U-boot log

```
$ qemu-system-arm -M virt -nographic -kernel u-boot 


U-Boot 2020.01-dirty (Mar 29 2020 - 15:46:14 +0530)

DRAM:  128 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
Flash: 128 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    pl011@9000000
Out:   pl011@9000000
Err:   pl011@9000000
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
=> timer
Unknown command 'timer' - try 'help'
=>
```

### Few more details

U-boot:

- repo : https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot.git
- branch / tag : v2020.01

Host OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: As far as I can see in https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot/-/blob/master/cmd/misc.c#L60 this command is under `#ifdef CONFIG_CMD_TIMER`. It means you have to enable it in the configuration file. Edit your *.config* or, if you wish to keep your changes survive longer, *qemu_arm_config* by adding `CONFIG_CMD_TIMER=y` to it and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doc/README.commands describes how commands should be implemented.

Your new C file should be in directory cmd/. In cmd/Makefile you will have to add your object file, e.g.

```
obj-$(CONFIG_CMD_TIMER) += timer.o
```

In cmd/Kconfig add a new configuration option for your command. The Kconfig syntax is described in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt.

Run

```
make menuconfig
```

to enable your configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

U-boot comes with a lot of stock commands which one can run on the u-boot console similar to the Linux console commands like 'ls'. The source for every command can be found under 'common/' directory with file names starting with 'cmd_'. However, not all commands are enabled by default.

From the code, you can open 'common/Makefile' and under the '# command' section you can find the list of all the commands masked with config flags 'CONFIG_*'. To enable a command, you have to simply #define the corresponding flag under the 'include/configs/.h' file and build the source. Now, you can see the command in the list of commands by running 'help'.

To enable a command 'source', in the 'common/Makefile', you can find

```
obj-$(CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE) += cmd_source.o
```

Simply include the corresponding flag in 'include/configs/.h' file as follows

```
obj-y += cmd_source.o
```

refer :[http://studyzone.dgpride.com/2016/11/u-boot-how-to-add-new-command-to-u-boot.html](https://studyzone.dgpride.com/2016/11/u-boot-how-to-add-new-command-to-u-boot.html)