# Beaglebone black emulation with QEMU

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

I am trying to run u-boot.bin for Beaglebone black on QEMU by using  below instruction:

$qemu-system-arm -M realview-pb-a8 -nographic -kernel /media/remo/xyz/EmbeddedLinux/u-boot-source-code/u-boot/u-boot.bin

First of all, whether the machine I am using here is appropriate for BBB as there is no machine listed for BBB I have used realview-pb-a8

By giving this instruction, it has taken almost 30mins but still I didn't get u-boot prompt.

u-boot.bin created by giving following instructions:

make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf- 
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf-_boneblack_vboot_defconfig

This is the first time I am running u-boot on qemu in the process of learning Embedded Linux.

Please help me around.

Answer (score 1):

Running a U-Boot compiled for one board on a QEMU configuration for another machine is bound to fail.

If you want to run U-Boot in QEMU you should build one of the QEMU targets:

- qemu_arm64_defconfig
- qemu_arm_defconfig
- qemu_mips64_defconfig
- qemu_mips64el_defconfig
- qemu_mips_defconfig
- qemu_mipsel_defconfig
- qemu-ppce500_defconfig
- qemu-riscv32_defconfig
- qemu-riscv32_smode_defconfig
- qemu-riscv32_spl_defconfig
- qemu-riscv64_defconfig
- qemu-riscv64_smode_defconfig
- qemu-riscv64_spl_defconfig
- qemu-x86_64_defconfig
- qemu-x86_defconfig

Instructions are provided in

- doc/board/emulation/qemu-arm.rst
- doc/board/emulation/qemu-mips.rst
- doc/board/emulation/qemu-riscv.rst
- doc/board/emulation/qemu-x86.rst

If you have a match between the emulated machine and the image you can also run other configuration. The following ones are known to be usable:

- vexpress_ca15_tc2_defconfig
- vexpress_ca5x2_defconfig
- vexpress_ca9x4_defconfig

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run u-boot on qemu then try the following:

1. Get `u-boot` source.
2. Prepare u-boot config files using `make qemu_arm_config ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-`
3. Build u-boot `make all ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-`
4. Launch qemu with u-boot image `qemu-system-arm -M virt -nographic -kernel u-boot`

You can check here [Implement custom u-boot command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913034/implement-custom-u-boot-command) . Here the question refers to implementing a new `u-boot` command but build instructions you can follow to boot u-boot on qemu.